# Cannot use 'd:' Prefix in front of attributes to enable Design Time Data

Tags: c#, xaml, design-time, xaml-designer

I have a problem with using `d:` in front of `attributes`, to display them in the XAML Designer.

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ControlForProjectSettings, Path=ViewModel}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" d:DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ControlForProjectSettings, Path=ViewModel}">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeadingTextBlocksStyle}" Text="Project Settings" d:Text="Test"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Only the `d:DataContext` property gets resolved but `d:Text` tells me *The property text does not existing in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" namespace*
Of course I am using the following lines of code in my header XAML document:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
```

This is one of my sources that i read: [Use Design Time Data with the XAML Designer in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-designtime-data?view=vs-2019)
I am using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 and .NET Framework.
Any suggestions why it's not working for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, this only works for .NET Core.  In the referenced article it reads "*You can use d: with attributes for any UWP or **WPF .NET Core** control, like colors, font sizes, and spacing. You can even add it to the control itself.*"

Comment: That's right but when you move to the section **Requirements**, one bullet point says "_This feature is also available for .NET Framework in the Preview channel. To enable it, go to Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features, select New WPF XAML Designer for .NET Framework and then restart Visual Studio._ Unfortunately when I go to the Preview channel, I don't see this option. Any ideas why I can't see it?

Comment: Correct.  They have not implemented this as of 16.8.3 - still waiting for this myself.